# Error: Cannot find module 'serialize-javascript' after running npm start in ReactJS project, even though there it exists in directory node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

For some reason my `npm start` doesn't work anymore, cause: this occurred right after switching to some unused branch (with unrelated histories) and pushing any changes (not realizing that this branch was some outdated one), then `git checkout -f ""` back to the recent branch. Now it doesnt work for any of my branches due to error `Error: Cannot find module 'serialize-javascript'`

Full error here:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'serialize-javascript'
Require stack:
- /home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/rollup-plugin-terser/index.js
- /home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/workbox-build/build/lib/bundle.js
- /home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js
- /home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js
- /home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/rollup-plugin-terser/index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/rollup-plugin-terser/index.js',
    '/home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/workbox-build/build/lib/bundle.js',
    '/home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js',
    '/home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js',
    '/home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js',
    '/home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js'
  ]
}
```

The `node_modules/serialize_javascript` does exist and has a settings.json file in it:

```js
{
  "spellright.language": [
    "en"
  ],
  "spellright.documentTypes": [
    "markdown",
    "latex",
    "plaintext",
    "javascript"
  ]
}
```

I have tried running npm install (with -g as well, and in the node_modules/serialize_javascript dir) with output:

```
up to date, audited 1725 packages in 2s

130 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 critical severity vulnerability

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

And `npm audit`:

```
# npm audit report

node-serialize  *
Severity: critical
Code Execution through IIFE - https://npmjs.com/advisories/311
No fix available
node_modules/node-serialize

1 critical severity vulnerability

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

What's weird is that even checking `node -version` (node -v works now after sudo get-apt update) gives a similar `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/abdullah/ecommerce-recommend-frontend/–v'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Note: This only occurred after uninstalling node, then reinstalling in wsl with `sudo`:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm 
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt-get update
```

Any ideas? Might try to just get rid of node from windows even though I use WSL and then reinstalling everything

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just copied an old serialize_javascript module from a previous commit since it had more stuff than just the settings.json and ran `npm install` to get it working.